# When should prefer Callable over Runnable and why?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, runnable, callable

On SO, I found all theoretical difference between `Callable` and `Runnable` and all are almost similar. But, I didn't understand why was [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) introduced in later version ? What was the gap/flaws in Runnable, which `Callable` is capable of doing ? Anyone can explain with scenario where `Callable` is only solution ?

Comment: `Callable` can return a value and is typically associated with a `Future`, so you would consider using it when you want to return a value from the process

Comment: @MadProgrammer: shouldn't this comment be an answer?

Comment: @MadProgrammer appreciate your reply. But, will be great, if you can relate this with some sort of real-time scenario. :)

Comment: @jWeaver Downloading a file from a web server, where you want to return the `File` (or other reference) to the completed operation.  `Callable` can also throw an `Exception` (which can be further contained by the `Future`), so it makes it great for dealing with simple tasks, which can take time to run, allowing you to feed the results into another part of the program

Comment: @KDM IMHO, it's to short ;)

Comment: BTW real-time means; with consistent latencies, real-world means; in practical situations.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ohh got it. I mean to say real-world. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callable has two differences. It can return a value or throw a checked exception.

This make a difference when using lambdas so that even though you don't specify which one to sue the compiler has to work it out.

```
// the lambda here must be a Callable as it returns an Integer
int result = executor.submit(() -> return 2);

// the lambda here must be a Runnable as it returns nothing
executors.submit(() -> System.out.println("Hello World"));

// the lambda here must be a Callable as an exception could be thrown
executor.submit(() -> {
   try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter("out.txt")) {
      out.write("Hello World\n");
   }
   return null; // Callable has to return something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) does answer a big part of your question:

> The `Callable` interface is similar to `Runnable`, in that both are
>   designed for classes whose instances are potentially executed by
>   another thread. A `Runnable`, however, does not return a result and
>   cannot throw a checked exception.

So, you are jusing Callable instead of Runnable, if...

1. You need to throw a checked exception or...
2. You need to return an object (of course you could simulate this by giving your runnable an internal result object, etc. - but it's easier that way)

For example...

```
ExecutorService service = ... some ExecutorService...;
Callable<Integer> myCallable = new MyCallable( ... some parameters ... );
Future<Integer> future = service.submit( myCallable );
...
Integer myResult = future.get(); // will wait and return return value from callable as soon as done
```

Comment: Is it right to say that, `Callable` is a replacement of `Runnable`. Since, what we can do with `Callable` can't be done using `Runnable` whereas vice-versa is possible ?

Comment: As Callable is there since 1.5 and Runnable since 1.0, we could say Callable is an upgrade to Runnable. You cannot give a Callable to a simple Thread object, so you cannot do that with it, but there are better ways to use it. I would call Runnable the "simpler" way: If you only want to run something, use it. Callable is when you want to know if it's already done, want a result, etc.